# GridLayout gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout); crashes my app

Tags: android, android-layout, findviewbyid

Whenever I want to find my grid layout by ID my app crashes immediately upon starting. It is not a typo (I don't get any compiling errors).

It is the first thing I have declared in `onCreate` method so it doesn't crash because some other method would try to do something with the layout before the `findViewById` is called.

What could be the cause?

(I tried changing its ID, name... didn't work)

Part of the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView countdownView, expressionView, scoreView, resultView, goView;
LinearLayout linearLayout;
GridLayout gridLayout;
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
Random randomGenerator;
Button startGameButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
    //other code here}
```

Comment: Tried reading crash message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change casting from this:

```
GridLayout gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
```

To this:

```
android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
```

Answer (score 4):

replace your line by this

```
androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

`findViewbyId` is changed in android studio 3.*

refer

`findViewById()` signature change
All instances of the `findViewById()` method now return `<T extends View> T` instead of `View`. This change has the following implications:

This may result in existing code now having ambiguous return type, for example if there is both `someMethod(View)` and `someMethod(TextView)` that takes the result of a call to `findViewById()`.
When using Java 8 source language, this requires an explicit cast to View when the return type is unconstrained (for example, `assertNotNull(findViewById(...)).someViewMethod())`.
Overrides of non-final `findViewById()` methods (for example, `Activity.findViewById())` will need their return type updated.

```
EditText message=super.findViewById(R.id.txtmessage);
```

I am a new android learner. Directly trying codes of videos in my learning

Answer (score -2):

Either cast it like A.El Saeed mentioned in his answer

```
gridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
```

or post your XML code also because sometime, it may possible that there will be some typo in your XML code or maybe you are using different `grid layout id` than defined in the XML

Comment: findViewById returns generic type since support lib 26 I believe

Comment: @Tuby I know mate that it returns generic type but that doesn't mean everyone is using Support lib 26
sometimes it shows an error even if you have support lib 26 so I think before downvoting the question, contributors should wait for the person who have posted his/her query

Comment: He uses lib 26 because there is no cast and code compiles. He is having crash in runtime

Comment: @Mango did you solved your problem or still no success

Answer (score -3):

Change it

from

```
gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
```

to

```
gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
```

You should cast the result from `findViewById` function